# How to use "and" to combine two phrases?

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles, conjunctions

Sometimes, I am confused on the correct usage of "and".

Does

> A beautiful car **and a truck**

and

> A beautiful car **and a beautiful truck**.

have the same meaning? I want to know whether "beautiful" can be inherited by the noun "truck".

It is a dumb question, but I really want a clear explanation.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. However, it is hard to understand what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link to more clearly explain your question. Our [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages explain how to write a useful question. We hope you will ask more questions here!

Comment: Edited. I hope it is more clear this time.

Comment: To _distribute_ the modifier _beautiful_ to both nouns in your sentence, we use _and_ like this: **A beautiful car and truck.** Introducing another article before a subsequent noun "breaks" the inheritance: **A beautiful car and a truck.**

Comment: You need to repeat 'beautiful' if you want it to apply to both the car and the truck.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you sir, so the "beautiful " is distributed as default.

Comment: At the minimum, put your noun phrase into a *complete sentence*. Even better, use a complete sentence in context. The noun phrase suggested by @P.E.Dant can be problematic. For  instance  saying *The Ford Mustang is a beautiful car and truck* is probably not what you want to say.

Comment: For instance, in this sentence, "beautiful" is distributed to both nouns: **My friend Dave has a beautiful car and truck.** There is an interesting article on the subject [**here.**](http://theeditorsblog.net/2015/08/08/one-adjective-paired-with-multiple-nouns-a-readers-question/)

Comment: @AlanCarmack thanks, I am feeling I am on the right track.

Comment: It's not precisely true that an adjective is distributed _by default._ The article I link to above is very informative.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sure, I will take my time reading through it, you are very helpful !

Answer (score 1):

> A beautiful car and a truck

The truck is not beautiful or we don't know it's state of beauty.

> A beautiful car and truck

Both the truck and car are beautiful.

> A beautiful car and beautiful truck

Same as above.  Use this to emphasize that both are beautiful or to make it extra clear.